# Flutter - Firestore is returning null data to a map on inistate statement

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

Here is my code:

```
void initState() {
 likesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('likes').doc(currentUser);
 super.initState();
 likesRef.get().then((value) => data = value.data());
 postRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products');
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 print('data $data');
```

I'm getting null data but in firestore I have data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 likesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('likes').doc(currentUser);
 likesRef.get().then((value){
   data = value.data();
    setState(() {});
  });
 postRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products');
}
```

When overriding always call the super method first when overriding to make sure the parent class method is being called before doing anything else in your code. Then after retrieving the data you can call `setState` to rebuild the widget tree with the data value. The other way is to use `futurebuilder` widget.

Comment: thankyou Peter for your answer, it's work, but the first time readed is getting null, any ideas?

Comment: because retrieving data from firebase is done asynchronously, therefore the build method is getting called initially with data = null then when you call setstate it will build again with the data. check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: thank you again Peter for your time!, it's work perfectly!,later on the code it was not entering to some if, because i had blank spaces at start of some fields in firebase,